# What is the use of baseclass.bResult-=true

Tags: selenium

i have baseclass with below code. How it help us to find the status of execution?

```
public class BaseClass {
    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static boolean bResult;

    public BaseClass(WebDriver driver){
        BaseClass.driver=driver;
        BaseClass.bResult=true;
    }
}
```

This we have used in all the pageobject classes and also we will be calling this class in every script

Comment: `bResult` is a variable in your code. How are we suppose to know what is it used for? I'm ***guessing*** it will be set to `false` if the test fails and used in your reporting system, but its just a guess. We can't really answer this question.

Comment: you can refer the below code details - http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/selenium-automation-hybrid-framework/

here they have used the Baseclase.java to initiate all the page objects

Comment: so why BaseClass.bResult=true; is used here?